# How to properly format a JsonResult call

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using a JsonResult Action Method to pass data into my cshtml view via an Angular $http call. However I can't get my Angular code to filter/sort/display the Serialized Object the way it should.

To test I manually passed a Serializeable list directly to the view as an ActionResult parameter, serialized it with JsonConvert in a Razer block in the view, then passed that Json string directly to the angular ng-init function. when I do that it all displays fine; I can build a table with ng-repeat, filter things with ng-show etc.

However when I try and pass that same serializable object via `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` all my Angular that touches that data breaks and either does nothing or throws a runtime error.

Here's the debugging workaround that functions perfectly:

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{   
    DashboardViewModel data = ServiceCache.GetData();

    return View(data);
}
```

The view:

```
@model EngineeringWorkflowBusiness.Models.DashboardViewModel

<main class="container" role="main" ng-controller="processModel">

    <div class="jumbotron" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ItemList))">
           <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                        <td>{{item.info}}</td>
    </div>

</main>
```

The Angular:

```
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope) {

    $scope.init = function (model) {
        $scope.data = model;
    };

});
```

And here's the method I actually need to use, but doesn't work at all, displaying nothing, the table is empty.

The Controller:

```
    public JsonResult DataRefresh()
    {
        DashboardViewModel data = ServiceCache.GetData();

        return Json(data.ItemList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The View:

```
@model EngineeringWorkflowBusiness.Models.DashboardViewModel

<main class="container" role="main" ng-controller="processModel">

    <div class="jumbotron" ng-init="GetData()">
           <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                        <td>{{item.info}}</td>
    </div>

</main>
```

The Angular:

```
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.GetData = function() {
        $scope.LoadData();
    };

    $scope.LoadData = function() {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: '/Home/DataRefresh'
        }).then(function success(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }, function error(errResponse) {
            alert("ERROR!");
        });
    };  

});
```

There has to be something I don't understand about how JsonResult works because as far as I can tell `$scope.data` should be holding the exact same Json string in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Angular `$http` service returns a promise object with a `data` property which has the response body from your ajax call response. So use that

```
$scope.LoadData = function() {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: '/Home/DataRefresh'
    }).then(function success(result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
    }, function error(errResponse) {
        alert("ERROR!");
    });
};
```

Also, your HTML markup seems to be invalid. If you are rendering a table row, it should be inside a `table`, not a `div`

```
<table class="table" ng-init="GetData()">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td>{{item.info}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```